# How can I install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap on Angular 15?

Tags: angular

Trying both `ng install` or `npm install` fails:

```
The package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.1.1 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^14.1.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"13.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/node/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.


$ npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: hygieia-ui@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^14.1.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/node/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Answer (score 1):

skip the dependency tree checking.

`npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.0.0 -f

use the force comments